# Why does AS3's map callback require an additional two arguments?

Tags: function, actionscript-3, functional-programming

Say I have:

```
myArray = [1,2,3];
```

And say I have a util function somewhere else:

```
add3 = function(val) {
   return val+3;
}
```

Now if I want to use that as the call back for a map function, I have to do something like this:

```
add3Callback = function(currentValue, index, array) {
    return add3(currentValue);
}

myArray.map(add3Callback);
```

Attempting myArray.map(add3) results in "argument count mistmatch". It would be better that the map callback doesn't require the extra two arguments, because now I have to add wrappers to all my util functions in order to use them with map, which goes against some of the reasons for using map in the first place.

What am I missing here? Why is having those arguments be compulsory useful, other languages (including Javascript) don't seem to do it.

Comment: "other languages (including Javascript) don't seem to do it" that is a wrong statement since the Array map in AS3 is not part of the AS3 language but simply a framework implementation for the Array object. The map sorting method is a convenience method and you are free to use it or not just like you are free to write your own sorting methods. Complaining about the implementation of this method is ridiculous and pointless, you are complaining about using a method that doesn't fit your needs then don't use it!

Comment: What other languages besides JavaScript allow you to call a function with incorrect arguments and not throw an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's the way it is.

If you want to work around that, just write function that does that. Why on earth would you want to write a specific wrapper function for each function to be passed to Array.map()?

```
function map(array:Array, callback:Function):void
{
   array.map(function(currentValue, index, array):void { callback(currentValue);});
}
```

It's really strange to complain about the necessity of wrapping function calls into each other and claiming Javascript to be different, because in js, for scope reasons, you wrap things in additional function calls all the time, except in this case.

Comment: I don't think doing it your way would work? You'd need a return statement in there, at which point the calling code becomes myArray = map(myArray, add3) which isn't functional at all. The niceness of doing things the functional way comes from simply being able to use existing functions without any extra work.

Comment: Your code isn't using the return value either and it's trivial to add it to my code. After all, my code is just the generalisation of your `add3Callback` illustrating the fact that you do not need individual wrapper functions.

Answer (score 0):

Because AS3 is stricter than JS. Specifically, you cannot call a function with incorrect arguments. Example:

```
function f(a){}
f(1,2,3); // JS allows this, AS3 does not
```

[This article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/actionscript3_overview.html) may help you understand the design choices behind AS3 (which, BTW, was based on ES4 which would have become JS if it wasn't abandoned for ["political reasons"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Versions)):